# How to solve $ \frac{dS(t)}{S(t-)}=\mu dt+\sigma dW(t)+d\left( \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}\left( V_{i}-1\right) \right) $

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations, levy-processes

Hey I found following Ito formula for jump diffusion process. Let

$$X_{t}=X_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}b_{s}ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma_{s}dW_{s}+\sum_{i=1}%
^{N_{t}}\Delta X_{i},$$
where $N_t$ is Poisson process and $W_t$ is standard Wiener process. Then

$$dY_{t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\left(  t,X_{t}\right)  dt+b_{t}%
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(  t,X_{t}\right)  dt+\frac{\sigma_{t}^{2}%
}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(  t,X_{t}\right)  dt+\frac
{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,X_{t})\sigma_{t}dW_{t}+\left[  f(X_{t-}+\Delta
X_{t})-f(X_{t-})\right]
$$

Now I have to solve this SDE:
$$
\frac{dS(t)}{S(t-)}=\mu dt+\sigma dW(t)+d\left(  \sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}\left(
V_{i}-1\right)  \right)  ,
$$

Where $V_i$ are i.i.d  random variables. $S(t-)$ means left limit and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by solving it ?

Comment: @TheBridge i.e. find a process  $S_t$ which satisfies this equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking note that if $Y_t$ is compound process and $Z_t$ is diffusion without jumps then $d(Y_t.Z_t) = dY_t + dZ_t$

Trying to solve separately

- $dS^1_t= S^1_t(\mu dt +\sigma dW_t)$
- $dS^2_t= S^2_{t-}.dY_t$

and then looking at both solution will lead $S_t=S^1_t.S^2_t$ to be the result.

The first equation I well known and has solution $S^1_t=S^1_0.e^{(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}).t+\sigma.W_t}$ so I won't go too much in the details (look on the web on geometric Brownian motion).

The second one has solution :
$S^2_t=S^2_0.\Pi_{k=1}^{N_t}V_k$

Thank's to [proposition 20.14](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MA5182/stochastic-calculus-jump-processes.pdf)  with $\lambda$ and $\mu_s$ equal to $0$, and $\eta_{T_k}=1-V_k$.

So piecing all this together using $f$ leads to unless mistaken :

$$S_t=S_0.exp((\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}).t+\sigma.W_t).\Pi_{k=1}^{N_t}V_k$$

Regards